# Javascript timezone offset not compatible with python datetime

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, timezone

I want to parse a string generated by javascript that looks like: **2021-03-10 03:15 -180**
I'm using the parser from datetime in python and it doesn't recognize the timezone offset generated by javascript. Any ideas?

```
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-03-10 03:15 -180
```

Comment: Consider fixing the javascript to generate a standards compliant offset so "-180" is "+03:00" or "+0300".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the date and timezone offset differently. You can do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
my_date = '2021-03-10 03:15 -180'
date_string, tz_offset = my_date.rsplit(' ', 1)
dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + timedelta(minutes=int(tz_offset))
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

which will give you the correct time in UTC. If you need to work with a different timezone, you can convert the time to another timezone using `dt.astimezone(my_new_timezone)`